# Modify numeric data type to set its minimum to 1

Tags: java, class, inheritance, data-structures, long-integer

I want to have a numeric data type starting at 1. Not use negative and 0.

So I could use Example class

```
public class Example extends Long {

    private int min = 1;

    public LifeTime(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

How could I change the min value of Long class with 1 at this Example data type class?

Is it possible to modify Long by extending the class?

Comment: Could you give a complete example? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not possible to extend `Long`, it is declared as `final`

Comment: I have a field where the user could type there Long. However, I do not want to allow the user to type 0. I do not have regex condition otherwise I might do it like that. However, I want to limit the Long.class so that the user could only type from 1 to max of Long.

Comment: Yes I saw it as an error @Amongalen how is it possible to modify it somehow?

Comment: You can't modify such class.

Comment: Usually, you do not solve such a "trivial" limitation of valid input values with an extra class. Instead, use a _Validator_ to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the constructor as a way to add the validation.
E.g.:

```
public class LifeTime {

private static final int MINIMAL_VALUE = 1;
private long value;

public LifeTime(long value) {
    if (value < MINIMAL_VALUE) {
        this.value = MINIMAL_VALUE;
    } else {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```